# MDI Parent's FormClosing event always closes one MDI child

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an MDI parent with this `FormClosing` event handler:

```
private void FrmMdiParent_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

and when I click the red cross on the window when I have some MDI children present, it will close exactly *one* MDI child. When I remove `e.Cancel = true`, the behaviour is the same, except it will close the parent form when all children are gone.

The children have no `FormClosing` handler registered.

How do I cancel the `FormClosing` event without closing any MDI children?

Comment: I think you also have to register `FormClosing` event handler for your child forms.

Comment: @KingKing seems like it yes, the `CloseReason` is different, so I can discern the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(Form f in yourMDIForm.MdiChildren)
    f.FormClosing += ChildFormClosing;
private void ChildFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){
    if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.MdiFormClosing) e.Cancel = true;
}
```